# Implementing infinite wait in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

This may sound trivial, but I'm pretty sure this question hasn't been asked, or at least I can't find it.

I'm looking for a way to construct an **infinite wait** (not necessarily a loop) with shell scripting so that it **waits forever and can be killed** (or technically, to receive a `SIGTERM`). The following are known possible constructs and arguments against them:

1. `while true; do sleep 1; done` This almost gets it, but since `sleep` is an external command, when I send a `SIGTERM` to the running script, it has to wait for the `sleep` to finish first and then process the signal. Change `sleep 1` to something like `sleep 10` and the lag will be obvious. Also the solution wakes up the CPU every 1 second, which is not ideal.
2. `while true; do read; done` This is perfect when `stdin` is tty. `read` is a shell builtin and `SIGTERM` arrives at the script instantly. But, when `stdin` is `/dev/null`, the script eats up all the CPU by helplessly running `read` forever on `/dev/null`.

Thus a **shell builtin construct** that waits forever is required. Skimming through `man dash` I didn't find such one - the only blocking builtins are `read` and `wait`, and I don't have idea how I can construct an ideal one using `wait`.

The answer should be applicable to POSIX shell (effectively `dash`), or less preferably, Bash.

**Additional notes.**

The situation where the first example doesn't work perfectly is more complex than I thought. With the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
while true; do
    sleep 100
done
```

if you kill it at another tty, it terminates immediately. The funny thing begins when you attempt to do trapping. With this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
at_term() {
    echo 'Terminated.'
    exit 0
}
trap at_term TERM
echo $$
while true; do
    sleep 20
done
```

What happens is exactly described in example 1. This happens with bash, dash and zsh. And it's under this condition that I'm seeking a "perfect" infinite look construct.

Comment: When I send a `SIGTERM` to a `dash` executing `sleep 100` in a loop, it exits immediately.

Comment: What do you require this for? If the process should persist but do nothing, it could send itself a `SIGSTOP`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use a named pipe for your read:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
#or mknode /tmp/mypipe p
```

if you later want to send different arbitrary "signals" to the pipe, the read can be use in combination with a case statement to take appropriate actions (even useful ones)

```
while read SIGNAL; do
    case "$SIGNAL" in
        *EXIT*)break;;
        *)echo "signal  $SIGNAL  is unsupported" >/dev/stderr;;
    esac
done < /tmp/mypipe
```

Comment: Yes, this one is virtually perfect. I'll see if someone can came up with something simpler or I'll accept...

Comment: Accepted your answer :) It's universal under all circumstances.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a solution without a loop:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/dash

echo $$

# -$$: kill process group (parent and children)
#trap 'trap - TERM; kill 0' TERM
#trap 'trap - INT TERM; kill 0' INT TERM

trap 'trap - TERM; kill -s TERM -- -$$' TERM

tail -f /dev/null & wait

exit 0
```

Comment: Your script is magic! it is the only one which does what I want (response to signal 15). Could you explain it in details please? so why you repeated trap in trap? the whole things written in trap are not clear for me, and why & after tail, and why wait after all?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin The `trap - TERM` part removes the existing trap handler for the script, so that the same signal won't be caught again.

The `kill -s TERM -- -$$` part sends `SIGTERM` to all processes in the same process group. Effectively all child and descendant processes (including the script itself). I.e. a negative PID is a PGID as far as `kill` is concerned, but we need an extra `--` to not confuse with command switches.

As the `SIGTERM` handler has been removed, the script will terminate when receiving the second `SIGTERM` signal (that it sends in the old handler).

Answer (score 10):

If you have GNU coreutils, which accepts floating-point seconds, you can try:

```
sleep inf
```

This should block until the 64-bit timestamp wraparound.

Comment: if you don't have `inf` (e.g. on alpine/sh), you can always just put this in an infinite loop.  Either way, this works a treat

Comment: This doesn't work if only the shell script (and not the *sleep(1)* process) receives the signal.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your 2nd option but forcing it to read from `stdin` ? (Requires `bash`)

```
while true; do
  read
done < /dev/stdin
```

From `man bash`

> Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in
>   redirections, as described in the following table:
>
> ```
>           /dev/stdin
>                  File descriptor 0 is duplicated.
> ```

Comment: I cannot find much documentation about /dev/stdin, therefore it's reasonable to suspect it may not be always available.

Comment: It would be very nice if someone can came up with some documentation regarding /dev/stdin :)

Comment: It breaks when stdin is redirected to /dev/null. Put that in a.sh and run `bash a.sh < /dev/null` and see the CPU being eaten...

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
at_term() {
  echo 'Terminated.'
  exit 0
}
trap at_term TERM
echo $$
while true; do
  sleep 20 &
  wait $!
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Personally I think it's more elegant than using `read`, and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

SIGTERM sent to a process is delivered by the kernel  to the process whether  it is sleeping or not.

Try experimenting, maybe like this (bash example)

```
sleep 20 &
kill $! && fg
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use `sleep forever`? This is designed to forever block.

Comment: Because that will not allow the script to handle the SIGTERM signal like the author explained.